# Unable to use youtube-dl or annie to download video from Bilibili

Tags: youtube-dl

So I was trying to download a video from Bilibili using annie. I oroginally chose youtube-dl but unfortunately it doesn't seem to support Bilibili website, so I chose annie instead, following the advice from [a reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/comments/ctz456/theres_still_no_way_of_downloading_videos_from/)
But despite it seems I have no luck using Annie either. I wonder if this is because Bilibili has updated their mechanism or if I made a mistake somewhere.
This is the code.

```
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % annie "https://www.bilibili.com/s/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2"
Downloading https://www.bilibili.com/s/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2 error:
this page has no playlist
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Also, youtube-dl claims it supports [Bilibili](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html) and I definitely remember downlowding video from Bilibili using youtube-dl not so long ago. So what happened. Did Bilibili update their code or something?

```
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % youtube-dl "https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846?p=1"
[BiliBili] 90163846: Downloading webpage
[BiliBili] 90163846: Downloading video info page
WARNING: Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 412: Precondition Failed
[BiliBili] 90163846: Downloading video info page
ERROR: Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 412: Precondition Failed (caused by 
HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using 
the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the -- 
verbose flag and include its complete output.
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

edit:
Here is the debug log if it is of any help.

```
 apple@192 ~ % youtube-dl -v "https://bilibili.com/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2"         
[debug] System config: [u'--format', u'mp4', u'-o', u'~/Desktop/%(title)s.%(ext)s', u'--write-sub', u'--embed-subs']
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'-v', u'https://bilibili.com/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2021.03.14
[debug] Python version 2.7.16 (CPython) - Darwin-20.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 4.3.1, ffprobe 4.3.1, rtmpdump 2.4
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[BiliBili] 1TD4y1R7k2: Downloading webpage
[BiliBili] 1TD4y1R7k2: Downloading video info page
ERROR: requested format not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 806, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 838, in __extract_info
    return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 872, in process_ie_result
    return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1675, in process_video_result
    expected=True)
ExtractorError: requested format not available

apple@192 ~ %
```

Comment: Have you reported the issue to YouTube-dl has instructed by the error message?

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to do to fix this:

1. Upgrade to the current version of youtube-dl. The Bilibili extractor was last changed on 8/March/2021 and when I tested with an older version, it didn't work
2. Use Bilibili URLs that look like `https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2` as the input for youtube-dl.
   Don't use Bilibili URLs like the first example that has a **/s/** in it. So instead of `https://www.bilibili.com/s/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2`, you should use `https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2`

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work.:(apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % youtube-dl -U
youtube-dl is up-to-date (2021.03.14)
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ % youtube-dl "https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2"
[BiliBili] 1TD4y1R7k2: Downloading webpage
[BiliBili] 1TD4y1R7k2: Downloading video info page
ERROR: requested format not available
apple@apples-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Comment: Your exact command works for me. Please provide the output of this command: `youtube-dl --version`

Comment: Hi，the response is 2021.3.14

Comment: That's exactly what I have and it works for me. Try this and post the response: `youtube-dl -v "https://bilibili.com/video/BV1TD4y1R7k2"`

Comment: See the edit. Too long to post comment

Answer (score 0):

add the following in the command

--add-header Accept:'*/*'

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.